# "rake db:create:all" without including "bundle exec"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I mistakenly created my databases using `rake db:create:all` without including `bundle exec`. Should I remove all the databases and recreate them using `bundle exec rake db:create:all`?

Comment: bundle exec simply runs the command within your given gem environment.  This shouldn't be necessary to create the databases, so no, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle exec rake db:create:all` executes the rake script with the command db:create:all in the context of the current bundle. 
In some cases, running executables(like db:create:all) without [bundle exec](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html) may not work, if the executable is not  installed in your system or pulls in any gems that conflict with your bundle. 
But since in your case, it worked fine without returning any errors, **removing and recreating databases is not required**.

Comment: Newer versions of `bundler` and `rubygems` make doing an explicit `bundle exec` less necessary.